# Prevent access from add-on domain root to other folders

Tags: linux, hosting

I've been trying to figure out if add-on domains can be prevented from accessing folders outside its specified root folder. I host multiple websites on one big hosting plan and am trying to avoid a compromise in one of the sites from allowing access to the directories above it.

How would I go about doing this using htaccess, permissions, or any other method? or is this even possible to do in the first place?

I am using Amazon Lightsail VPS to host these sites.

Comment: We don't accept questions about systems using cPanel or other mass web hosting software. You should contact cPanel support for this issue.

Comment: note the edit @MichaelHampton

Comment: You edited your question, you didn't reinstall your server without cPanel. It's still not acceptable.

Comment: @MichaelHampton so the doesn't specifically apply to that server. In the case of a VPS running apache, is this achievable? Because the same issue is present there. lol

Comment: cPanel implements many things in strange ways, and only cPanel engineers know how it works. Therefore it is not possible to answer cPanel related questions here. You need to contact cPanel support.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Yea that seems to be the consensus haha but this also applies to my Amazon Lightsail VPS.